# Rails - How does 'will_paginate' plugin work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

[Will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/%20%22Will_paginate) plugin allows whatever ActiveRecord to get paginated.

Indeed, a `paginate` method is available within this ActiveRecord. For example, if I want to paginate `Order`, I do:

```
Order.paginate page:params[:page], order: 'created_at desc'
```

How `paginate` method is created? Is this the [Will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/%20%22Will_paginate) plugin that does some kind of: "taking ActiveRecord definition and injecting a `paginate` method into?

Furthermore, to keep this example, if the above assumption is correct:

How to avoid conflict with the plugin if for whatever reason, `Order` has defined a proper paginate with a totally different purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will_paginate uses the extend method to add modules to the ActiveRecord::Base class. See https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb#L202

If Order also has a method called paginate then it will override the ActiveRecord::Base#paginate method.